# Извлечение png из exe файла

Tags: c#

Как извлечь готовую картинку (png) из скомпилированного EXE-файла после нажатия на `button`?

Answer (score 2):

Если картинка внедрена в ресурсы исполняемого файла, который и извлекает ее оттуда, это можно сделать так:

```
// Код копирует файл, внедренный в ресурсы в локальную папку (не тестировалось)

string path = Application.LocalUserAppDataPath + "\\Picture.png";
if (File.Exists(path)) 
    File.Delete(path);

var input = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Picture.png");
var output = File.Open(path, FileMode.CreateNew);

byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
while (true)
{
    int read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (read <= 0)
        break;
}

input.Dispose();
output.Dispose();
```

При данном подходе не имеет значения тип встраиваемого файла (это может быть txt, jpg, doc и т.п.).

Comment: выводит ошибку в строке -> "int read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);" 

что делать???

Comment: Что за ошибка хоть?

Answer (score 1):

Извлечь вшитый в exe ресурс (картинку) можно методом `GetManifestResourceStream` класса `Assembly`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xc4235zt.aspx?ppud=4)